# Change button color according to the pallet chosen color

Tags: angularjs

I have a pallet of colors that open clicking in a square button, like this:

```
  <div class="dropdown color-picker-dd">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
   <div class="container dropdown-menu">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-3">
         <span class="color-preview" ng-click="updateOutputColor('#b60205')" ng-style="{'background-color': '#b60205'}"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
         <span class="color-preview" ng-click="updateOutputColor('#d93f0b')" ng-style="{'background-color': '#d93f0b'}"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
         <span class="color-preview" ng-click="updateOutputColor('#fbca04')" ng-style="{'background-color': '#fbca04'}"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
         <span class="color-preview" ng-click="updateOutputColor('#0e8a16')" ng-style="{'background-color': '#0e8a16'}"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And I want to change the button color to the color picked from the pallet.

UPDATE: JS:

```
// Update output color.
$scope.updateOutputColor = function (color) {
  ProjectService.editProjectOutputColor($scope.project, color).then(function () {
    $scope.switchOutputColor(color);
  });
};

// Output color swticher.
$scope.switchOutputColor = function (color) {
  // if color is empty or undefined, fallback to original css.
  if ((color === '') || (color === null) || (color === undefined)) {
    color = '';
  }

  $scope.outputFontColor = {'color': color};
  document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].addRule('.output-header i:before', 'color: ' + color);
};
```

Comment: Where is the function `updateOutputColor()` ?

Comment: @Weedoze Updated the question with the function part

Comment: You are not using `$scope.outputFontColor` variable

Comment: @Weedoze I'm using it to change other elements color with `ng-style="outputFontColor"`, but it doesn't work on the button

Comment: Then simply add `$scope.outputBackgroundColor = {'background-color': color}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can change the button colour as shown below, also check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MIli9kVTriNE1SDSAkLm?p=preview) for your example scenario as sample.

**Template:**

```
<button class="btn-default" ng-style="customStyle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Change My Color</button>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.updateOutputColor=function(colorName){
    $scope.customStyle={
      'background-color': colorName
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, this works for the button, but the other elements don't change color now

Comment: When you say other elements what are the others? can you please mention?

Comment: Others like titles and `divs` that have `ng-style="outputFontColor"` to change color when you pick one from the pallet. That was the whole point of the `updateOutputColor` function, but I also want it to change the button color, like most color pickers do

Comment: I have update the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MIli9kVTriNE1SDSAkLm?p=preview). Can you please check.